# how to Direct fetch of the record after registration by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I want to fetch the records by Ajax immediately after each record is set by Ajax and show it by the table.
I was able to save the records in the database with Ajax, but after registering the records with Ajax, I want to call them as a list with Ajax without refreshing the page.

I want to fetch the records by Ajax immediately after each record is set by Ajax and show it by the table.
I was able to save the records in the database with Ajax, but after registering the records with Ajax, I want to call them as a list with Ajax without refreshing the page.

[image]

```
 [HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateSubmitProjectStap2(Project project)
{
    var pro = _context.Projects.Find(TempData["ProID"]);
    pro.KhdamatHesabrsee = project.KhdamatHesabrsee;
    pro.SabteProjectDate = DateTime.Now;
    pro.MablghGhrardad = project.MablghGhrardad;
    pro.ShoroeeProjectDate = project.ShoroeeProjectDate;
    pro.PayanProjectDate = project.PayanProjectDate;
    pro.MashmolArzeshAfzoode = project.MashmolArzeshAfzoode;

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { status = "ok" });

}
```

---

```
                <form >

                    <table class="table table-bordered text-sm " width="100%">

                        <thead class="text-center">

                            <tr style="background-color:#416992; color: white">
                                <th>نوع خدمات</th>
                                <th>مبلغ قرارداد</th>
                                <th style="width:180px">تاریخ شروع</th>
                                <th style="width:180px">تاریخ پایان</th>
                                <th>مشمول ارزش افزوده</th>
                                <th>عملیات</th>

                            </tr>

                        </thead>

                        <tr>

                            <td>

      <select class="form-control" asp-for="KhdamatHesabrsee"  required autocomplete="off">

                                    <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                                    <option value="1">حسابرسی</option>
                                    <option value="2">مالیاتی</option>
                                    <option value="3">منابع انسانی</option>


                                </select>

                            </td>

   <td><input class="form-control"  asp-for="MablghGhrardad" autocomplete="off" /></td>

                            <td>


  <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon"
                                         style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                                        <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="bgainDate" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" asp-for="ShoroeeProjectDate" />

                                </div>

                            </td>

                            <td>

  <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon"
                                         style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                                        <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input  id="EndDate" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" asp-for="PayanProjectDate" />

                                </div>


                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center">

 <input type="checkbox" style="width: 1.25rem; height: 1.25rem; top: .8rem; " class="flat-red" value="1" asp-for="MashmolArzeshAfzoode">
                            </td>
4

                            <td class="text-center">

                                <button id="btn-send" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" > <i class="fa fa-save"> </i>ذخیره </button>

                            </td>


                        </tr>


                    </table>

                </form>
```

---

```
$("#btn-send").on('click', function () {

$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateSubmitProjectStap2", "Project")',
    data: {
        'KhdamatHesabrsee': $("#KhdamatHesabrsee").val(),
        'MablghGhrardad': $("#MablghGhrardad").val(),
        'ShoroeeProjectDate': $("#ShoroeeProjectDate").val(),
        'PayanProjectDate': $("#PayanProjectDate").val(),
        'MashmolArzeshAfzoode': $("#MashmolArzeshAfzoode").val(),

    }
}).done(function (res) {
    if (res.status == 'ok') {
        $("#ohsnap").removeClass('hidden').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').html('گام دوم با موفقیت ثبت شد');
    }
    else if (res.status == 'error') {
         $("#divmsg").removeClass('hidden').addClass('alert-danger').html('در ثبت اطلاعات خطایی رخ داده است');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Hi @stoo frisat, if you want to display the list in current page, you can return partial view and use `.html` to display the html. If you want to display list in another page, you can use `window.location="url"` to redirect to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the list in current page, you can follow the steps below:

Model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string KhdamatHesabrsee { get; set; }
    public DateTime SabteProjectDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShoroeeProjectDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PayanProjectDate { get; set; }
    public string MablghGhrardad { get; set; }
    public bool MashmolArzeshAfzoode { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Project
<form>
    <table class="table table-bordered text-sm " width="100%">
        <tr>      
            //...           
            <td>
                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"
                         style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                        <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input id="bgainDate" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" asp-for="ShoroeeProjectDate" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"
                         style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                        <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input id="EndDate" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" asp-for="PayanProjectDate" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">  
                <input type="checkbox" style="width: 1.25rem; height: 1.25rem; top: .8rem; " class="flat-red" asp-for="MashmolArzeshAfzoode">
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <!--add type="button"-->
                <button type="button" id="btn-send" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success"> <i class="fa fa-save"> </i>ذخیره </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="list"></div>  <!--add list div-->
```

JS:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#btn-send").on('click', function () {  
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateSubmitProjectStap2", "Project")',
                data: {
                    'KhdamatHesabrsee': $("#KhdamatHesabrsee").val(),
                    'MablghGhrardad': $("#MablghGhrardad").val(),
                    'ShoroeeProjectDate': $("#ShoroeeProjectDate").val(),
                    'PayanProjectDate': $("#PayanProjectDate").val(),
                    'MashmolArzeshAfzoode': $("#MashmolArzeshAfzoode").val(),

                }
            }).done(function (res) {
                $("#list").html(res);   //use .html to display the html
               $("#ohsnap").removeClass('hidden').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').html('گام دوم با موفقیت ثبت شد');
            }).fail(function (res) {
                alert(res.responseText);
                $("#divmsg").removeClass('hidden').addClass('alert-danger').html('در ثبت اطلاعات خطایی رخ داده است');
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Partial view(_ProjectList.cshtml):

```
@model List<Project>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model[0].KhdamatHesabrsee)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model[0].MablghGhrardad)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model[0].MashmolArzeshAfzoode)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model[0].PayanProjectDate)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model[0].SabteProjectDate)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model[0].ShoroeeProjectDate)</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KhdamatHesabrsee)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MablghGhrardad)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MashmolArzeshAfzoode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PayanProjectDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SabteProjectDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShoroeeProjectDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateSubmitProjectStap2(Project project)
{
    try
    {
        var pro = _context.Projects.Find(TempData["ProID"]);
        pro.KhdamatHesabrsee = project.KhdamatHesabrsee;
        pro.SabteProjectDate = DateTime.Now;
        pro.MablghGhrardad = project.MablghGhrardad;
        pro.ShoroeeProjectDate = project.ShoroeeProjectDate;
        pro.PayanProjectDate = project.PayanProjectDate;
        pro.MashmolArzeshAfzoode = project.MashmolArzeshAfzoode;
        _context.Update(pro);   // be sure add update or insert operation...
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }          
    return PartialView("_ProjectList",_context.Projects.ToList());
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to display the data in another page, you can use  `window.location` in frontend.

View:

```
@model Project
<form>
    <table class="table table-bordered text-sm " width="100%">
        <tr>              
            //...                    
            <td><input class="form-control" value="dsf" disabled asp-for="MablghGhrardad" autocomplete="off" /></td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"
                         style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                        <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input id="bgainDate" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" asp-for="ShoroeeProjectDate" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group" style="padding-left:9px; padding-right:9px;">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"
                         style="border:1px solid gray; padding:6px">
                        <span>  <i class="right fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input id="EndDate" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" asp-for="PayanProjectDate" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">

                <input type="checkbox" style="width: 1.25rem; height: 1.25rem; top: .8rem; " class="flat-red" asp-for="MashmolArzeshAfzoode">
            </td>
            4
            <td class="text-center">
                <!--add type="button"-->
                <button type="button" id="btn-send" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success"> <i class="fa fa-save"> </i>ذخیره </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JS:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#btn-send").on('click', function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateSubmitProjectStap2", "Project")',
                data: {
                    'KhdamatHesabrsee': $("#KhdamatHesabrsee").val(),
                    'MablghGhrardad': $("#MablghGhrardad").val(),
                    'ShoroeeProjectDate': $("#ShoroeeProjectDate").val(),
                    'PayanProjectDate': $("#PayanProjectDate").val(),
                    'MashmolArzeshAfzoode': $("#MashmolArzeshAfzoode").val(),

                }
            }).done(function (res) {                                 
                window.location = "/ControllerName/Test";  //add this line...
            }).fail(function (res) {
                alert(res.responseText);
                $("#divmsg").removeClass('hidden').addClass('alert-danger').html('در ثبت اطلاعات خطایی رخ داده است');
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Another View named Test.cshtml(the same with _ProjectList.cshtml):

```
@model List<Project>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model[0].KhdamatHesabrsee)</th>
            //...
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model[0].SabteProjectDate)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model[0].ShoroeeProjectDate)</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KhdamatHesabrsee)
                </td>
                //...
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShoroeeProjectDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller(must contain an action called `Test`):

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateSubmitProjectStap2(Project project)
{
    try
    {
        var pro = _context.Projects.FirstOrDefault();
        pro.KhdamatHesabrsee = project.KhdamatHesabrsee;
        pro.SabteProjectDate = DateTime.Now;
        pro.MablghGhrardad = project.MablghGhrardad;
        pro.ShoroeeProjectDate = project.ShoroeeProjectDate;
        pro.PayanProjectDate = project.PayanProjectDate;
        pro.MashmolArzeshAfzoode = project.MashmolArzeshAfzoode;
        _context.Update(pro);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }         
    return Ok();

}
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return View(_context.Projects.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thankful.What should I do if I want to display the list on another page without pressing the button? I mean in $ (document) .ready (function ()

Comment: For example, show _context.Projects.ToList () on another page with ajax. Please edit the answer. Thank you very much

Comment: For your first comment.  If you do not use button, you cannot know when your inputs have been typing completed.  For the second comment, so you want to display the model list in another page?

Comment: Because your record has been updated to the database, so just use window.location to redirect to another action and return view with model to display the updated list. Please check my updated answer.